# Why do I need to modify <master> if I want to merge it into my public <feature1> branch according to Atlassian Stash?

Tags: git, pull-request, bitbucket-server

This is the current situation. The repo has both a public `<master>` and then a public `<team1>` branch:

```
o <-- master
 \
  o <-- team1
```

Both branches are considered as [public](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing).

When using Atlassian Stash, we want to do update the `<team1>` branch with the  with the latest that has been delivered to the `<master>` so we have created a Pull Request. Source is `<master>` and the target is `<team1>`.

However, when doing that Atlassian Stash is showing us that it cannot be merged due to conflicts and here is how to resolve them for the Pull Request:

[image]

But this guide will result in that you have pushed up a merge conflict into `<master>`. Why?

Is this setup with `<master>` and `<team1>` branches wrong and using Pull Requests?

Doesn't it make more sense to resolve any conflicts in the `<team1>` branch and leave `<master>` totally unmodified (until `<team1>` will deliver back to `<master>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because any git pull requests is based on the principle that merge conflicts are always resolved in the source branch than in the target branch. Normally, target branches are where more than 1 people integrate their codebases, so it makes sense to resolve any conflicts in the source branch than in the target branch.

If you want to get around this , you can checkout the  branch and do a git branch from master, and resolve the conflicts in  branch and push them up

Answer (score 1):

A pull request usually signals that you want your code merged "towards production", and Stash's instructions are based on conflict resolution in that situation.

Rather than creating a pull request for updating a feature branch from master, it would be simpler to just carry out a merge, and resolve any conflicts that come up.

I'm the product manager for Stash and this isn't the first time I've seen this come up. I'm thinking about the best way to keep people on the safest path here, and make sure the guidance given makes sense (be it in avoiding unnecessary pull requests, or gracefully handling unusual ones).

Comment: Sounds good: "it would be simpler to just carry out a merge, and resolve any conflicts that come up"